# How to fix "domain error" in SQL Server 2005 when using LOG() function to get product of set

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a inline select statement to calculate the product of the set of values.

Since SQL Server 2005 doesn't have a built in Product aggregate function, I am using LOG/EXP to get it.

My select statement is:

```
(select exp(sum(log(value))) from table where value > 0)
```

Unfortunately I keep getting the following error:

```
Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A domain error occurred.
```

I've ensured that none of the values are zero or negative so I'm not really sure why this error is occurring.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the features of the query planner introduced in SQL 2005 is that, in some circumstances where the table statistics indicate it will be more efficient, the `WHERE` clause of a statement will be processed after the `SELECT` clause.
(I can't find the Books On-Line reference for this right now).

I suspect this is what is happening here. You either need to exclude the rows where `value = 0` before carrying out the calculation - the most reliable way being to store the rows you need in a temporary (#) table - or to modify your query to handle zero internally:

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(ISNULL(NULLIF(VALUE,0),1)))) AS result 
FROM [table]
```

The `NULLIF\ISNULL` pair I have added to your query substitutes 1 for 0 - I think this will work, but you will need to test it on your data.

Comment: You're right, I believe this is exactly what was happening.  What I ended up doing was to add a CASE statement within the LOG() statement to handle 0 and NULL values.

Comment: To be more accurate I would add this little extra to be sure you get a result of 0 when you have a VALUE = 0 in your set (assuming you have only positive values): SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(VALUE) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE EXP(SUM(LOG( ISNULL(NULLIF(VALUE,0),1) ))) END AS result FROM [table]